# window open not working in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function that work properly it allows me to display a hide fields depending the option selected in **role select field**. the select field in var **formgroup2** **variable** after the adress field has an onchange event that should open a modal window when **create new office is selected**. This part is not working when i add it to the function but out of the function it works.

```
  function hide () {
  console.log("whatever")
  }
  function visibilite1(_this) {
 var formgroup1 = '<div id="test1" class="divs"><label>Name </label> <input type="text" name= "name" id= "name" required>  </br><label>User  name </label><input type="text" name= "username" id= "username"    required></br><label >Password <em>*</em></label><input   type="password"   name= "password" id= "password" required></br></div>'

var formgroup2 = '<div id="test2" class="divs"><label>Name </label<input type="text" name= "name" id= "name" required> </br><label>User  name </label><input type="text" name= "username" id= "username"   required> </br><label>Password <em>*</em></label><input type="password"  name= "password" id= "password" required> </br> <label>Adress<em>* </em></label><input type="text"   name= "adress" id= "adress" required></br>  <select name="office" id="office" onchange="goToPage()"  required> <option value="">select office </option> <?php   while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($req)) {echo"<option   value=".$d['OfficeName'].">".$d['OfficeName']."</option>";   }mysqli_free_result($req);  ?><option value="Create new office"   style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">create new office</option></select>
</div>'
var formtestElement = document.getElementById('formtest'); 
 if (_this.value == "test1") {
  formtestElement.innerHTML = formgroup1
} else if (_this.value == "test2") {
  formtestElement.innerHTML = formgroup2
};
}


<select name="role" id="role"onchange="visibilite1(this);hide()" >
<option value='test1'>Year1</option>
<option value='test2'>Year2</option>
</select>

<div id="formtest">
<div id="test1" class="divs">
<label>Name </label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>  </br>
<label>User name </label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" required></br>
<label>Password <em>*</em></label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></br>
```

Comment: Yeah I can't read that at all, good grief. That whole `formgroup2` thing sure seems broken, though.

Comment: Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: The string for `formgroup2`'s onchange isn't properly closed. Edit: On second glance, you're using `"` inside of `"`.. You need to escape it.

Comment: Window. open will not open a modal window.

Comment: thank you so much i just re formatted my codes please review my post

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="office" 
        id="office" 
        onchange="var maVal = 
document.getElementById(" office ").value; if (maVal =="Create new office ")
{window.open("newOfficeCreate.php ", "blank ", "scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, top=50, left=155, width=1200, height=700 ");"} 
        required>
```

You never close the `onchange` attribute.

I think. It's really hard to tell. Trying to inline stuff like that is just horrible; write a function and either reference it if you feel you must use attributes, or attach it later.

Comment: thank you so much i just re formatted my codes. Sorry. Please review my post

Comment: @branche Your question has already been answered here and in a comment, and further you were told that `open` has nothing to do with being a modal window, but that may be because you're using "modal" differently than people do.

Comment: i make the correction of Dave Newton. it's still not working.

Comment: i replace it by document.location.href="createOffice1.php it's still not working

Comment: i don't use window.open any more instead i use document.location.href to go to another page once the select is equal to Create new office. it's still not working please have a look

Comment: @branche One of those line is 1K long :( It's not reasonable to expect people to read that. Without the actual code, in a way that's actually reasonable, I don't think you're going to get much further assistance. You need to extract the `onchange` handler to a JS function instead of trying to inline it, at the very least, and post your actual code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise i correct my codes and it's working perfectly, i edited i just created  the function apart in the onchange and i call it goToPage(). thank you so much. i hope you remove my (-2).

Comment: @branche Glad you got it working. I can't control who votes what, though :)